# Rigify Eye Bones Are Broken

Tags: bones, rigify

it's me again. This time I'm trying to rig another creature named Cometo. Everything has been working out fine except for the head. I know I'll have to weight paint, but the most problematic part of it is the eyes. I don't know if this is supposed to happen, and I'll have to explain it the best I can. So, this is the rig in edit mode.
[image]
Edit Mode.

But, in pose mode, this is what happens:

[image]
In pose mode.

Any idea to what is happening? I tried clearing rotations, locations, and scales, but nothing changed. It probably has to do something with the axis it has, because every time I change the axis, it seems to change the shape.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is being affected by another bone. You need to find out which one.
You can try this method: https://youtu.be/BNEjLCNi4Xs?t=900